# Activity with selectable ListView and ActionBar in Android

Tags: android

I don't know what should I do to implement a selectable ListView and show the selected items in the Action Bar. I guess there is a native and quick way to do that, but I don't know how to search it! Could anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the sample  under samples of your sdk

```
android-sdk-linux/samples/android-17/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List16
```

Use the below for reference and modify it accordingly.

Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] GENRES = new String[] {
            "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy",
        "Documentary", "Drama",
            "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi",
        "Television", "Thriller"
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, GENRES));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Long press to start selection");
    }

    private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_select_menu, menu);
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shared " + getListView().getCheckedItemCount() +
                        " items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mode.finish();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = getListView().getCheckedItemCount();
            switch (checkedCount) {
                case 0:
                    mode.setSubtitle(null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

list_select_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/share"
          android:title="share"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Under res/values-v11/styles.xml. Using this will set the selected item to blue color.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

    <style name="activated" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Add the style to the root element of your layout.

```
 style="@style/activated"
```

Snap shot

[image]